# Why is the set of algebraic elements a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

Let $E/F$ be a field extension.Let $A$ be the set of algebraic elements over $F$:
elements $a$ so that there exists an $f\in F[x]$ so that $f(x)$.
The lecturer has mentioned that $A$ is a subfield of $F$ and I can't understand why.

I've searched for an answer here and got the main idea: if $[F(a): F], [F(b), F]$ are finite, then so must be $[F(a, b):F]$. But I can't see why it's so.

My attempt:
we know that there are degrees $m, n$ so that $1, a, ... , a^m$ is a basis for $F(a)$ and $1, b, ... , b^n$ is a basis for $F(b)$.
It seems intuitive to claim that $\left \{ a^ib^j \right \}$ is a basis for $F(a, b).$ It is certainly true for the **ring** $F[a, b]$, but, for example, why would $\frac{1}{a^2b+ab+1}$ be a linear combination of such?

And if I'm already asking: the intuitive way to attack this problem is, given a polynomial with $a$ as a root and one with $b$ as a root, constructing a polynomial with $a+b$ or $ab$ as a root. It seems like there is no good way to do so. Am I right?

Thank you!

Comment: Search the web for _algebraic elements form a field_.  Here are some links: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/81638/constructive-proof-of-algebraic-elements-forming-a-subfield, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206034/alternative-proof-that-set-of-algebraic-elements-is-a-subfield

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two solutions : one is going in with your hands and finding polynomials that work for $a+b, ab$.

Another way is a more linear kind of thing.

Consider $a,b$ algebraic over $F$. Then $ab, a+b \in F(a,b)$.

But $b$ is a root of a certain polynomial with coefficients in $F$, so we can say the same about a polynomial with coefficients in $F(a)$, therefore $[F(a)(b):F(a)]$  is finite.

But also $[F(a) : F]$ is finite.

Now the telescopic basis theorem states that $[F(a,b): F(a)][F(a): F] = [F(a,b) : F]$. But $F(a,b) = F(a)(b)$ and so $[F(a,b):F(a)]$ is finite and thus $[F(a,b):F]$ is also finite : $a+b, ab$ are algebraic over $F$.

The argument you didn't see is the telescopic basis theorem. It's proved by noting that if $(u_i)$ is a basis of $F(a,b)$ over $F(a)$ and $(v_j)$ of $F(a)$ over $F$, then $(v_j u_i)$ is a basis of $F(a,b)$ over $F$ (which is simple to show, once you know what you have to show)

Comment: Oh, now I see. Slipped out of my mind. Thank you

Comment: Dear Max, do you know any reference where the result above is proved constructively?

Comment: @Xam : I know there are constructive proofs of this result, but unfortunately I don't know any reference. If I recall correctly, the polynomial over $F$ for $a+b$ is $\displaystyle\prod_{i,j} (X - a_i - b_j)$ where the $a_i$ are the conjugates (over $F$) of $a$ and the $b_i$ those of $b$; and it's similar for $ab$. I'm not sure about this but I think a technical argument allows to prove that this polynomial has coefficients in $F$

Comment: What is telescopic basis theorem you used ?

Comment: @PritamRoy : that if $E/K$ is a field extension, with a basis $(e_i)$ of $E$ over $K$, then for any vector space $V$ over $E$ with basis $(v_j)$, then the family $(e_iv_j)_{i,j}$ is a basis of $V$ over $K$. In particular, $\dim_K(V) = \dim_E(V) \dim_K(E)$