# A question about proving field to algebraic extension of other field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

This question was part of my assignment in Field Theory course and I was unable to solve it.

> Let $E_1$ and $E_2$ be subfields of F and X a subset of F. If every element of $E_1$ is algebraic over $E_2$ , then prove that every element of $E_1(X) $ is algebraic over$E_2(X) $.

Attempt: it is not necessary that $E_1$ must be be proper subfield of $E_1$ .

Except the above statement which is due to comment of Gerry Myerson I don't have any other clues on how this question should be attempted.

So, please tell how to prove what was asked.

Comment: I don't see how you could possibly prove $E_1(X)$ is a subfield of $E_2(X)$. Say $F$ is the rationals adjoin $\sqrt2$ & $\sqrt3$, and $E_1$ is the rationals adjoin $\sqrt2$, and $E_2$ is the rationals adjoin $\sqrt3$. Then every element of $E_1$ is algebraic over $E_2$, but $E_1(X)$ is not a subfield of $E_2(X)$.

Comment: Any reaction to my comment?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson I am really busy . I  am studying and trying complex analysis problems. I will get back to it as soon as I can. I am  really sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Ya you are right . It can't be proved. I think I made a wrong conclusion. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, recall that if $L/K$ is a field extension then the set of elements of $L$ that are algebraic over $K$ is a subfield, $L^\mathrm{alg}$. see, for example [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2210445/why-is-the-set-of-algebraic-elements-a-field).

In your situation, let $F^\mathrm{alg}$ be the set of elements of $F$ algebraic over $E_2(X)$. We want to show that $E_1(X)$ is a subfield of $F^\mathrm{alg}$. Certainly $E_1$ is a subset of $F^\mathrm{alg}$ since $E_1$ is algebraic over $E_2\subset E_2(F)$. Also, $X$ is clearly a subset of $F^\mathrm{alg}$ since it consists of elements of $E_2(X)$. Thus the field generated by $E_1$ and $X$, namely $E_1(X)$, must be a subfield of $F^\mathrm{alg}$, as needed.